# Generate Waveform from http audio live streaming

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, http-live-streaming

I need to generate a waveform for live streaming url while it's playing, 
I tried `MTAudioProcessingTap` but the there is no tracks on the url(it's empty),

I have checked other libraries that generate WaveFroms such as AudioKit however it doesn't support http live streaming.

Any help?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://github.com/dmrschmidt/DSWaveformImage

Comment: Thanks @A.Munzer, but it's the same, it will not help with live streaming

Comment: Have you found something ?

Comment: Very useful question. I wish there was and an answer.